# configure an elasticsearch index with json not taking

Tags: json, indexing, elasticsearch, config

I'm using the following json to configure elasticsearch. The goal is to set up the index and the type in one swoop (this is the requirement, setting up docker images). This is as far as I've gotten that will allow elasticsearch to start successfully. The problem is that the index isn't created yet it doesn't error. Other forms I've tried prevents the service from starting.

```
 {
"cluster": {
    "name": "MyClusterName"
},
"node": {
    "name": "MyNodeName"
},
"indices": {
    "number_of_shards": 4,
    "index.number_of_replicas": 4
},
"index": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "my_ngram_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer",
                "filter": "lowercase"
            },
            "my_lowercase_whitespace_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                "filter": "lowercase"
            }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
            "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
                "type": "nGram",
                "min_gram": "2",
                "max_gram": "20"
            }
        }
    },
    "index": {
        "settings": {
            "_id": "indexindexer"
        },
        "mappings": {
            "inventoryIndex": {
                "_id": {
                    "path": "indexName"
                },
                "_routing": {
                    "required": true,
                    "path": "indexName"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "indexName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "startedOn": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "deleted": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "deletedOn": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "archived": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "archivedOn": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "failure": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "failureOn": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
   }
 }
```

I may have a workaround using curl in a post-boot script but I would prefer to have the configuration handled in the config file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that elasticsearch will not allow all the configuration to be done in a single yml. The workaround I've found is to create an index template and place it in the `<es-config>/templates/` dir then after spinning up the service I use curl to create the index. The index matching will catch it and provision it according to the template.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html